# Proper way to get data-attr value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is one way preferred over the other?  If so, why?  Or are there better ways?

```
var something=$('#something').attr('data-something');
var something=$('#something').data('something');

<p id='something' data-something='hello'>goodby</p>
```

Comment: Short: for simple values `attr('whatever')` is great and enough. `.data()`  can store more complex data such as objects easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you want to get, they do different things.

`.attr('data-something')` will get you the initial value.

`.data('something')` will get you the current value.

If you use `.data('something', 'goodbye')` to change the value, after that using `attr` will get you `'hello'` and `data` will get you `'goodbye'`.

Comment: Fair answer.  What if I was only interested in the initial value?  What would you recommend.

Comment: `attr()` for the initial value @user1032531

Comment: @user1032531: If the data never changes then either works. I would recommend `data`, mostly because it is meant for reading data attributes. If it changes and you need the initial value, you need to use `attr`.

Answer (score 1):

`.data()` is generally a more useful function because it can, among other things, parse data types. If you have an element with value `data-something="15"` and add 1 to it with `.attr("data-something") + 1`, you'll get 151, whereas if you use `.data("something") + 1` you'll get 16. `.data()` can also parse booleans and JSON.

One drawback of `.data()` is that, as @Guffa noted, it doesn't actually modify DOM elements, so if you have other code that reads the new value of the attribute after `.data()` modifies it, you should use `attr()` instead.

`.data()` is overall a much more powerful and better function, but there are plenty of situations in which it is actually detrimental and the less-powerful `.attr()` should be used in its place.

http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5